# kafka-node not consuming message

Tags: node.js, npm, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have the following code which uses kafka-node module:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node')
var Consumer = kafka.Consumer
var client = new kafka.Client("example.com:9092/")
var consumer = new Consumer(
    client,
    [
      { topic: 'some_event', partition: 0, offset: 0}
    ],
    {fromOffset: true}
  );

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
  console.log("received message", message);
});
```

I took most of the help from the official documentation but that doesn't seem to be working.

When I try to use node-rdkafka ( a different module to consume events), it works well.. here is the code with this:

```
var Kafka = require('node-rdkafka');
var consumer = new Kafka.KafkaConsumer({
  'group.id': 'some_event',
  'metadata.broker.list': 'example.com:9092',
}, {});
consumer.connect();

consumer
  .on('ready', function() {
    consumer.subscribe(['build_status_events']);
    consumer.consume();
  })
  .on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.value.toString());
  });
```

But I can't use node-rdkafka due to my production environment limitation.

Can anyone please help me to find out where I am doing wrong in the first program.

Comment: Are you not able to get any message at all or does it get stuck?